# How can I iterate through an array once per day?

Tags: java, android, arrays

So I'm working on an application that needs to display a value, a specific string of text once per day. I have all my strings in an array and now I just need a way to increase the index once per day. The kicker is that if the user downloads the application later in the year I need to have all the other days accounted for. So basically the user will see the same tip as a person who downloaded the app on the first day. Any suggestions?

Would using the Calendar class be my best bet? I just don't want to set an individual switch and case for every day of the year.

Comment: arrays cannot change their size. `ArrayList` can.

Comment: Maybe use a `Map` wiith the Date as a key and the text as value.

Comment: I second the notion of using the date as a key.  Then everyone will get the same value on the same day no matter what.

Comment: Perhaps write a utility that given a start date and a file containing the strings will generate the initializer for the map.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "increase an array". Do you mean you want to increase *the size* of the array? Or do you want to change some value *in* the array?

Comment: Given the rest of the problem description, I think it means "increment the index being used to access the array.".

Comment: you'll need to use (currentDate - installDate) as the index/key into the tip array/table. That will ensure the user sees the same sequence of tips

Comment: As an alternative to the suggestiong by @mohaps, you can use a Map instead of an array. That way you can index by the date directly.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly (Bob downloaded the app a hundred days ago should see the same tip as Alice who downloaded the application today), you can use Calendar's DAY_OF_YEAR value to display the same date

```
    Calendar ca1 = Calendar.getInstance(); //get today's date

    int DAY_OF_YEAR=ca1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) -1; //DAY_OF_YEAR starts at one

    //avoid IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions
    String tip = tiparray[DAY_OF_YEAR % tiparray.length];
```

Comment: It's better if you use a non-cyclical value (number of days since jan 1, 2000?) - if he has 360 questions and uses DAY OF YEAR, his first 5-6 questions will repeat at the end of the year.

Comment: you could use `(ca1.getTimeInMillis / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) % tiparray.length` to achieve that.  That will get you the number of days since jan 1 1970

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand completely the question. I think you will need to have the same tip shown for everyone in each day, right?

If so, you can use Calendar.DAY_OF YEAR :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int index=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: DAY_OF_YEAR for calendar starts at 1, so index 0 will never be hit